# Android studio doesn't create project structure

Tags: android-studio, project-structure

I am new to Android studio. I tried to create my first project and there is no project structure only gradle files. What am I doing wrong? I keep getting these files with creation of another new project.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was my problem. I updated Android studio from version 1.x to 2.x. On official site is written that if you try to install version 2.x into same location Android studio might not work properly and there could be some unexpected behavior.

So just removing Android studio and then reinstaling it, worked perfectly.

Comment: I installed fresh and automatically updated.  I still get this structure though.  Perhaps I am overlooking something?

Comment: Try to uninstall studio. And then download the lates version from web

Comment: I think I found the problem.  Android Studio only came with `API Level 17`, but the new project wizard targeted `API Level 18`.  When I fixed this the structure was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Update SDK via Android SDK Manager. You need all packages in Tools to be installed.
But even after doing so, I can't make it to auto generate resources. So I continue to deal with it...